# wordpress admin can't post new post after migrating to new server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Read a lot to resolve this but I am stuck...:-(

Moved a WP site from shared to linode VPS.

**Configs**:

**WordPress** 3.6.1
**mysql** Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.5-m15, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
**PHP** 5.5.18-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2014 15:11:34)
**apache**
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 22:57:50
**DB** is ut8

**Virtual host conf file:**

```
DocumentRoot /home/userName/webSite

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

**.htaccess:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Admin in wp_usermeta Table:**

```
wp_capabilities
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}
```

So login is ok.
Edit post is working
**PROBELM:

New post has 'submit for review' button instaed of 'publish'!**
Clicking 'submit for review' gives 'you do not have suitable permissions to edit the post'

And I can't seem to find the problem.
I tried fixing file and folder permissions.
Adding define('WP_HOME' AND define('WP_SITEURL' to wp-config

I dont even know where to start...

wp_posts table has A_I on ID.
wp_posts DUMP shows:

```
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `wp_posts`
--
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts`
MODIFY `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=7633;
```

7633 is the next post ID.

How can I fix this??
Please ask any question as I have been through most of the fixes suggested on the web.

ThanX :-)

Comment: "Most of the fixes suggested on the web" is pretty vague, so I'm going with the standard: 1) deactivate all your plugins and try again; 2) switch to the TwentyEleven theme or whatever basic theme your WP installation has and try again; 3) Check that your user is still an administrator.

Comment: no need to deactivate plugin, just see my instructions in answer... hopefully will work for you

Comment: @Aioros-1)did-no good.2,3) will try @Adeel Mughal's and will post back. cheers

Comment: @Aioros-2,3)switched-user is still admin but no PUBLISH.

Comment: Just a random thought here: could it be that your DB is out of space?

Comment: @Aioros-double checked but no...it has plenty...

Comment: I had the same problem. My AutoIncrements (and indexes) where missing.

Answer (score 3):

### Migration means environment change

What's in your environment? Mysql for one!

Given that there's a migration involved, I bet it's something to do with your DB... you may be able to check logs to figure out what queries are failing. For me it was [**sql_mode**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html), specifically related to 0s in date times not being accepted. (happens on new post drafts).

Keep reading to solve the sql_mode, if that's your issue.

### Check your sql_mode

To check what your current `sql_mode` is, you can do this in mysql (probably as a root mysql user): `SELECT @@sql_mode;`

Wordpress uses 0s for "null" date times, and some sql mode settings do not allow that. I believe there are plugins out there that try to solve this 0s for dates problem at the application layer (within wordpress), but I think that may be a bit hacky...

I opted to switch my sql_mode and made my sql mode only `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` because wordpress is the only thing using my database and I'm okay with that sql_mode for my project. You may need to preserve most of the settings in your sql_mode setting, but just remove the no zero in date option, so that's why you should check what your current sql_mode is before resetting it.

### What are the sql_modes by default?

> The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 includes these modes: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, and NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.

So, you may want to remove `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE` from yours if you find it present, and preserve the rest.

### Where do I change my sql mode?

> To set the SQL mode at server startup, use the --sql-mode="modes"
>   option on the command line, or sql-mode="modes" in an option file such
>   as my.cnf (Unix operating systems) or my.ini (Windows). modes is a
>   list of different modes separated by commas. To clear the SQL mode
>   explicitly, set it to an empty string using --sql-mode="" on the
>   command line, or sql-mode="" in an option file.

I set mine in **options.cnf** or **my.cnf** on my server for the mysql program.

Comment: I had a similar issue and your advice worked for me. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Solution

Define a new admin user

Log in with that admin user

Lower your previous admin to contributor

Increase it back to administrator

Log in with your original admin

It will now work.

Delete the new admin

Now it's back to normal.

Comment: @AdeelMunghal-repeated this with another user with no luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find which did the trick, after many different other solutions out there was to install a fresh copy of WordPress4.0.1 and that fixed everything.